# How to deal with portion waterfall layout UICollecionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

[image]

For this ViewController,I plan to divide it into two parts.

One part is a UITableView on the top,another is a UICollectionView for the WaterFall View on the bottom.Make they height equal to they contentSize'height.Add them to a UIScrollView and let scrollView's height equal to (UITableView's height + UICollectionView's height).

**This is my collectionView part:**

[image]

I use custom UICollecitonView flowlayout.

However,for both UITableView and UICollectionView,they **did't reuse cell** when  it's height=contentSize's height.

So I have to change my plan.

Another idea is use a UICollectionView **for all the ViewController**.But for a UICollectionView only a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

**The difficulty is only the bottom part is waterfall layout not all the page is waterfall layout.**

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot if anyone can provide an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cell containing a `UICollectionView` with the `WaterFallLayout` and the height of this cell will expand automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To create any custom layout, you have to create a layout of your own.
What i mean to say is that, whether the collectionview has a waterfall design halfway and then flow or any layout you require, you have to create a custom layout of the collectionview, that will behave according to the data. The height, pattern and everything you desire.
[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2) is a nice tutorial on how to achieve this.

P.S - I know giving link is not accepted in stackoverflow, but the code and explanation of custom layout is so quite big and its explained here in a nice way.

Hope it helps